# Compiz config won't start

Tags: 11.04, ccsm

a month ago I asked a question regarding the `CCSM` and workspaces settings.

[How do I set the number of workspaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38801/how-do-i-set-the-number-of-workspaces-without-ccsm)

A few days ago I realized that CCSM wasn't even on when I'm logging into Ubuntu, and now, each time I log out and back in, I have to use  `compiz --replace &`  just to run it manually, which is quite a pain to do each time.
Since I upgraded to Natty Narwhal I got this problem.

I was wondering what do I need to do in order to fix that problem (needless to say that reinstalling CCSM doesn't really work).

Thnx
Royi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with Compiz not starting on Ubuntu 11.04 Classic. I found a fix [here](http://ubuntu4beginners.blogspot.com/2011/05/force-unity-compiz-to-run-natty-narwhal.html) (and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40798/classic-mode-missing-desktop-effects-after-updates) was my topic).

Answer (score 0):

You could just add    `compiz --replace &` to your startup applications...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the gnome-control-center, and click on the Startup *applications* button. In the dialog that just should have appeared, click the add button. In the command field, paste the `compiz --replace &` command, type something like *Compiz* in the name field, this is just to identify it for yourself. Click the *Add* (or *OK*) button, and close the dialog.

Comment: This is not a fix but work around.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to tell Gnome to use compiz as your default window manager and not use metacity at all. Simply put this in your ~/.gnomerc 
(create that file if it does not exist yet):

`export WINDOW_MANAGER=/usr/bin/compiz`

Spread the word!

as for the fusion icon , its only purpose is to switch windows managers and if you're committed to compiz and have added this file, then the icon is pretty much renundent unless you really need to game that bad (or your system es...)