# Why is my card Unity blacklisted with all the requirements fulfilled?

Tags: unity, nvidia, blacklist

The following is the Unity test output:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce FX 5500/AGP/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  2.1.2 NVIDIA 173.14.30

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          no
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          no
```

As you can see, all requirements are fulfilled but my GPU is blacklisted. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Geforce FX 5700, with Unity not starting on Ubuntu 11.04. I found a fix [here](http://ubuntu4beginners.blogspot.com/2011/05/force-unity-compiz-to-run-natty-narwhal.html) (and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40798/classic-mode-missing-desktop-effects-after-updates) was my topic). Now I'm running in Ubuntu Classic (including effects) without problems.

Comment: I am already running Ubuntu Classic with effects, but Unity does not work.

Comment: No icons in launcher (though I didn't reboot yet), but I can live with it.

Answer (score 4):

FX cards seem to be blacklisted:

```
  // jaytaoko: Balcklist the Geforce FX cards
  if (results->renderer != NULL) {
    char* str = strstr (results->renderer, "GeForce FX");
    if (str != NULL) {
      results->flags |= FLAG_BLACKLISTED;
    }
  }
```

Here's the reason why: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/772207